# Sort Data from object which is inside an array and the array is too inside another array

Tags: php

This is my array whose name is **ClassSectionMapObjArray** which contains **StudentSectionObjectArray** and this contains **StudentSectionObject**.

In **StudentSectionObject** there is a **studentObj** Array from which i have to fetch **studentName** alphabetically.

```
Array 
    ( 
        [0] => GetClassSectionMap Object
        ( 
            [studentSectionObject] => Array 
            ( 
                [0] => StudentSection Object 
                ( 
                    [studentId] => 1
                    [studentObj] => Array 
                    ( 
                        [0] => Student Object 
                        ( 
                            [studentName] => Varun Gupta
                        )
                    )
                )
                [1] => StudentSection Object 
                ( 
                    [studentId] => 2 
                    [studentObj] => Array 
                    (
                        [0] => Student Object 
                        ( 
                            [studentName] => Shubham Sharma
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
```

I have to store data in Alphabetical order by **studentName.**

I'm a learner, new to php.. Please help.
I have also use **usort()** too but it doesn't work.

```
usort($class_section_map_object_array[0]->studentSectionObject,"cmp");

function cmp($a,$b)
{
    return strcmp($a->studentObject->studentName,$b->studentObject->studentName);
}
```

But This gives me result in **descending order** according to **studentId**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, i have solved that ..

A little change in my function, and thats it...

```
function cmp($a,$b)
    {
        return strcmp($a->studentObject[0]->studentName,$b->studentObject[0]->studentName);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

without using strcmp instead of blow code

```
usort($class_section_map_object_array[0]->studentSectionObject,"cmp");

function cmp($a,$b)
{
    return $a->studentObject->studentName < $b->studentObject->studentName;
}
```

Comment: No change... Same as previous

Comment: I think so you need to put usort($class_section_map_object_array[0]->studentSectionObject,"cmp"); function after that cmp function completed